# Organizing boxes by calling a method using material UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am very new to material UI, typescript, and react, so if I say something incorrect or use the wrong terminology please correct me. I have 4 boxes that I want to place on a page, but three boxes have to go in a row and stacking the 4th on the bottom of the box 1.

I currently have a grid as a parent that holds these boxes together as shown

```
<Grid container={true} spacing={1} justifyContent="center" alignItems='flex-start'>
    <Box sx={{m: 1}} style={{width: '500px', height: '600px'}}>
      <SomeData data={defaultDeploymentFrequencyData}/>
    </Box>
    <Box sx={{m: 1}} style={{width: '500px', height: '600px'}}>
      <SomeData data={defaultDeploymentFrequencyData}/>
    </Box>
    <Box sx={{m: 1}} style={{width: '500px', height: '600px'}}>
      <SomeData data={defaultDeploymentFrequencyData}/>
    </Box>
    <Box sx={{m: 1}} style={{width: '500px', height: '600px'}}>
      <SomeData data={defaultDeploymentFrequencyData}/>
    </Box>
  </Grid>
```

Instead of using boxes all the time and editing them there, is there a way that i can call a method so that it aligns them correctly

```
export const BoxLayout = ():JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <Box>
      sx={{
        display: 'grid',
        gap: 1,
        gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(2, 1fr)',
      }}
    </Box>
  )
}
```

I am thinking this could be called when laying out the boxes, maybe like

```
<Grid container={true} spacing={1} justifyContent="center" alignItems='flex-start'>
  <BoxLayout>
   <SomeData data={defaultDeploymentFrequencyData}/>
   <SomeData data={defaultDeploymentFrequencyData}/>
   <SomeData data={defaultDeploymentFrequencyData}/>
   <SomeData data={defaultDeploymentFrequencyData}/>
  <BoxLayout>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to wrap each `Box` inside `<Grid item>` component.

```js
<Grid container spacing={1}>
  <Grid item xs={4}>
    <Box style={{ width: 50, height: 50}}>Box</Box>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={4}>
    <Box style={{ width: 50, height: 50}}>Box</Box>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={4}>
    <Box style={{ width: 50, height: 50}}>Box</Box>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={4}>
    <Box style={{ width: 50, height: 50}}>Box</Box>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Column widths are integer values between 1 and 12; they apply at any breakpoint and indicate how many columns are occupied by the component.
So by saying `xs={4}` you mean this box occupies 4/12 of the space or one third. Then last box goes to the next line under the first box.